# Asp.net DropDownList with Filter option

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

Is there way around i can add filter option with asp.net DropDownList control ?
Like, user start typing in it and it narrow downs the list beneath accordingly.

```
<asp:DropDownList id="ColorList" runat="server">
<asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="White"> White </asp:ListItem> 
<asp:ListItem Value="Silver"> Silver </asp:ListItem> 
<asp:ListItem Value="DarkGray"> Dark Gray </asp:ListItem> 
<asp:ListItem Value="Khaki"> Khaki </asp:ListItem> 
<asp:ListItemValue="DarkKhaki"> Dark Khaki </asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Thanks..
Anjum

Updated :

I have chosen JS but still not working for me, here is the code of my page :

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Chosen.aspx.vb" Inherits="Transactions_Chosen" %>



<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/chosen.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>



          <select class="chosen-select" style="width:350px;" tabindex="2">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="United States">United States</option>
            <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
            <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
            <option value="Lesotho">Lesotho</option>
            <option value="Liberia">Liberia</option>
            <option value="Pakistan">Pakistan</option>
            <option value="Palau">Palau</option>
          </select>




  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="../JS/chosen.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var config = {
      '.chosen-select'           : {},
      '.chosen-select-deselect'  : {allow_single_deselect:true},
      '.chosen-select-no-single' : {disable_search_threshold:10},
      '.chosen-select-no-results': {no_results_text:'Oops, nothing found!'},
      '.chosen-select-width'     : {width:"95%"}
    }
    for (var selector in config) {
      $(selector).chosen(config[selector]);
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, but not in the default asp.net controls stack. You will need 3rd party controls to accomplish this (Telerik, DevExpress etc.). There are some clientside jquery controls (like jquery chosen http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) but then you will need to different way of binding as you are used to with server side controls.

Answer (score 1):

If chosen might be a possible solution for you you could do this: (chosen.jquery can be downloaded via nuget. You should also get "chosen" as it provides some stylesheets).

**.aspx**

```
<select class="chosen-select" style="width:350px;" tabindex="2">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="United States">United States</option>
    <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
    <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="Lesotho">Lesotho</option>
    <option value="Liberia">Liberia</option>
    <option value="Pakistan">Pakistan</option>
    <option value="Palau">Palau</option>
</select>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var config = {
        '.chosen-select': {},
        '.chosen-select-deselect': { allow_single_deselect: true },
        '.chosen-select-no-single': { disable_search_threshold: 10 },
        '.chosen-select-no-results': { no_results_text: 'Oops, nothing found!' },
        '.chosen-select-width': { width: "95%" }
    }
    $(function() {
        for (var selector in config) {
            $(selector).chosen(config[selector]);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Well, it still not working. Please see updated portion for what i did and still not getting it rightly.

Comment: Your update is working perfectly for me. However, you could defer the assignment of the chosen object to document.ready. I'll update my answer....

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to use jQuery, you may look at this: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

It allows you to bind different data source to the combo-box (drop-down).